# Google calendar API: Copy conference data not working

Tags: google-calendar-api

We are trying to copy conference data from one event to other but it not working for non G-suite accounts. We are using Google.Apis.Calendar.v3 libraries for .net. Following is sample code :

```
Event firstEvent = service.Events.Get(calendarId, "eventId1").Execute();
secondEvent.ConferenceData = firstEvent.ConferenceData;
```

The same code works for G-suite accounts. Is there anything special that needs to be done for non Gsuite accounts or its not supported for them? May be we are missing something. Actually issue is instead of copy conference data it gives new conference data i.e new link, new signature even if same object is set to copy. It should give same link, same copy ConferenceData after creation, isn't it?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

References : 
https://developers.google.com/calendar/create-events
https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert

Comment: Conferences have some limitations for non-G Suite users. Can you share the content of the `Events.get`? Is it Meet or Hangouts? Thanks.

Comment: Its hangouts. Actually issue is instead of copy conference data it gives new conference data i.e new link, new signature even if same object is set to copy.

Answer (score 0):

This is an intended behavior. New events with attendees create a Conference automatically, so it's not possible to change it with the API. G Suite users don't have this limitation and can disable this option from the Admin console.

Comment: But it is not mentioned anywhere in their doc, they might have to add this otherwise some developers may use it but create problems on production server.